# In node.js, should a common set of data be in the database or a class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my database I have a table with data of cities. It includes the city name, translation of the name (it's a bi-lingual website), and latitude/longitude. This data will not change and every user will need to load this data. There are about 300 rows.

I'm trying to keep the pressure put on the server as low as possible (at least to a reasonable extent), but I'd also prefer to keep these in the database. Would it be best to have this data inside a class that is loaded in my main app.js file? It should be kept in memory and global to all users, correct? Or would it be better on the server to keep it in the database and select the data whenever a user needs it? The sign in screen has the listing of cities, so it would be loaded often.

I've just seen that unlike PHP, many of the Node.js servers don't have tons of memory, even the ones that aren't exactly cheap, so I'm worried about putting unnecessary things into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to give this a try. Using an example data set consisting of 300 rows (each containing 24 string characters and two doubles and property names), a small node.js script indicated an additional memory usage of 80 to 100 KB.

You should ask yourself:

- **How often will the data be used? How much of the data does a user need?**

  If the whole dataset will be used on a regular basis (let's say multiple times a second), you should consider keeping the data in memory. If, however, your users will need a part of the data and only once from time to time, you might consider loading the data from a database.
- **Can I guarantee efficient loading from the database?**

  An important fact is that loading parts of the data from a database *might* even require more memory, because the V8 garbage collector might delay the collection of the loaded data, so the same data (or multiple parts of the data) might be in memory at the same time. There is also a guaranteed overhead due to database / connection data and so on.
- **Is my approach sustainable?**

  Finally, consider the possibility of data growth. If you expect the dataset to grow by a non-trivial amount, think about the above points again and decide whether a growth is likely enough to justify database usage.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for going through all that to give an accurate answer. I'm actually really surprised at how high the memory usage is and I'll need to rethink some other aspects of my code as well. I'm using Sequelize as well, and they store loads of other data in the results they return, so there's quite a bit of additional overhead on the database queries as well. This data will be needed quite a lot, so I'm thinking maybe it's best in memory. Again, thanks for the good answer!